# How do you remove a role from a user?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to remove a role from a user with a command but I'm not quite sure how the command works.

Here is the code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role('staff')
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await bot.remove_roles(user, 'member')
    await bot.say("{} has been muted from chat".format(user.name))
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [`remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.remove_roles) needs a `Role` object, not just the name of the role.  We can use `discord.utils.get` to get the role

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role('staff')
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role = get(ctx.message.server.roles, name='member')
    await bot.remove_roles(user, role)
    await bot.say("{} has been muted from chat".format(user.name))
```

I don't know what happens if you try to remove a role that the target member doesn't have, so you might want to throw in some checks. This might also fail if you try to remove roles from an server admin, so you might want to check for that too.

Answer (score 4):

To remove a role, you'll need to use the `remove_roles()` method. It works like this:

```
member.remove_roles(role)
```

The "role" is a `role` object, not the (role's) name, so it should be:

```
role_get = get(member.guild.roles, id=role_id)  
await member.remove_roles(role_get)
```

With your code:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role('staff')
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role_get = get(member.guild.roles, id=role_id) #Returns a role object.
    await member.remove_roles(role_get) #Remove the role (object) from the user.
    await bot.say("{} has been muted from chat".format(user.name))
```

Comment: I may add that `get()` is from `discord.utils.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `remove_roles()` function takes two parameters, the first of which is the user from which the role and the role itself are removed.  It is possible **not** to write `user: discord.Member` in the function parameters, leave only `ctx`.  You also need the `role` you want to delete.  This can be done by:

```py
role = get (ctx.author.guild.roles, name = "the name of the role you want to remove")
#also include 'from discord.utils import get'
```

And then to remove the obtained `role` (object), call the function:

```py
await ctx.author.remove_roles (role)
```

So, the final code should look something like this:

```py
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role('staff')
async def mute(ctx):
    role = get (ctx.author.guild.roles, name = "the name of the role you want to remove")
    await ctx.author..remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("{} has been muted from chat".format(user.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('staff')
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild, name='member')
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'{user.name} has been muted from chat')
```